# When to play The Old Hunters? During the first run or NG+?

Tags: bloodborne

I'm doing my first Bloodborne run. I beat the boss of Byrgenwerth.

Currently I have the option of playing the new DLC, `The Old Hunters`.

If I waited until I finish my first run, it means I have to play the game again on NG+ in order to be able to play the DLC.

But according to what I read, recommended level to play the DLC is > 80

If that is true, it means that the DLC is even harder than the final stage of the game.

So when to play the DLC? Now during my first run? Or wait for NG+?

Comment: If you are able to play the DLC on your first run of the game, that would be an opinion based question and there would never be a true correct answer.

Comment: @Grirg It is about the difficulty level. > 80 to play it is a high number. So the question is: The DLC is for the players who finished the game or not yet?

Comment: Doesn't NG+ increase DLC difficulty as well? In that case, keep playing until you're closer to lvl 80 and then take on the DLC before starting the new cycle. Byrgenwerth is still quite a while away from the ending, so you have plenty of time/echoes to level up, if you find the DLC too difficult at that point.

Comment: I would not worry about recommend levels; they are meant for a guideline and nothing more. A true indicator is whether you perform well in the area or not. Try it out and if it is too difficult, return later as there's no shame in coming back when you're stronger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first run. I would **strongly discourage** continuing to NG+, because then the DLC areas will get harder just like everything else.

You have access to the DLC until you initiate the fight with the final boss. I would recommend occasionally checking in on the DLC and to see when it stops feeling too difficult for you, at which point you can do some or all of it.

The following spoiler about when the endgame begins is worded in the least spoilery way I can manage.

> There will a substantial *cosmetic* change to the Hunter's Dream when the final boss becomes available, but you are not cut off from the DLC until you speak with an NPC there.

The one after this line is very specific.

> After defeating Mergo's Wet Nurse in the Nightmare of Mensis, the workshop in the Hunter's Dream will catch on fire but remain usable. You will be able to speak with Gehrman in a previously inaccessible area. The dialogue choices you're presented with initiate a boss fight with him, or a cutscene where you let him kill you. The latter immediately boots you out to NG+.